# How can I show aggregate dimension weights across multiple grouping levels.

Tags: statistics, summation

Sorry for how long/complex this is. I've been trying to solve this for months and am hitting my head against a wall.

## Overview

To make sense of this, I have to explain the whole story.

- I have a bunch of `applications`
- Each application has a `manager`
- Each application has a `target score`
- Each application is scored on 3 `dimensions`
- The aggregate of those 3 `dimensions` is the application's `current score`
- Each application's `current score` should be under the `target score`

*(In my real world data I have 200+ dimensions. I am using 3 here for the sake of simplicity.)*

## Simple Example

Knowing the above, I can show the `weight` of each individual application + dimension combination. By `weight` I mean how much `weight` a specific `dimension` carries in bringing the `current score` to under the `target score`.

For example:

- Application's `target score` is `10`
- `dimension 1 score` = `1`
- `dimension 2 score` = `5`
- `dimension 3 score` = `15`
- Application's `current score` is = `1` + `5` + `15` = `21`
- The application needs to lower it's `current score` by `11`: `current score` - `target score` => `21` - `10`

  - I'll call this the `amount to drop by score`

Ergo:

- `dimension 1` has a weight of `0.09`: `dimension 1 score` / `amount to drop by score` => `1` / `0.09`
- `dimension 2` has a weight of `0.45`: `dimension 2 score` / `amount to drop by score` => `5` / `0.45`
- `dimension 3` has a weight of `1.36`: `dimension 3 score` / `amount to drop by score` => `15` / `1.36`

## So What?

This data tells me which dimension carries the most weight for fixing. In the above example, it's obvious fixing `dimension 3` is the best option cause it has the highest weight.

## Problem

Using the above method, I can show the `weight` for each `application` + `dimension` combination. Meaning, the weight for 1 `dimension` for 1 `application`.

**What I am trying to figure out how is how to calculate the `weight` by aggregating across managers?**

For example:

- What is the weight of `dimension 1` for `manager`?
- What is the weight of `dimension 2` for `manager`?
- What is the weight of `dimension 3` for `manager`?

## Complex Example

Say I have data like this:

| app ID | app name | l1 manager | target score | dimension 1 | dimension 2 | dimension 3 | current score | amount to drop by score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 35 | 9 | 15 | 59 | 10 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 50 | 22 | 30 | 102 | 70 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 45 | 18 | 50 | 113 | 67 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 19 | 41 | 13 | 73 | 30 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 1 | 38 | 16 | 55 | 17 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 48 | 38 | 24 | 110 | 73 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 5 | 3 | 36 | 44 | 8 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 16 | 44 | 41 | 101 | 56 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 6 | 50 | 43 | 99 | 55 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 13 | 29 | 25 | 67 | 30 |

I can restructure the data so each row is 1 `application` and 1 `dimension` to show it's `weight`:

| app ID | app name | l1 manager | target score | amount to drop by score | dimension name | dimension value | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 1 | 35 | 3.50 |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 2 | 9 | 0.90 |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 3 | 15 | 1.50 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 1 | 50 | 0.71 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 2 | 22 | 0.31 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 3 | 30 | 0.43 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 1 | 45 | 0.67 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 2 | 18 | 0.27 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 3 | 50 | 0.75 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 1 | 19 | 0.63 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 2 | 41 | 1.37 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 3 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 1 | 1 | 0.06 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 2 | 38 | 2.24 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 3 | 16 | 0.94 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 1 | 48 | 0.66 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 2 | 38 | 0.52 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 3 | 24 | 0.33 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 0.63 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 0.38 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 3 | 36 | 4.50 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 1 | 16 | 0.29 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 2 | 44 | 0.79 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 3 | 41 | 0.73 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 1 | 6 | 0.11 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 2 | 50 | 0.91 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 3 | 43 | 0.78 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 1 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 2 | 29 | 0.97 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 3 | 25 | 0.83 |

## Problem Details

But now, how can I create an aggregate table that shows `weight` by `l1 manager`?

| l1 manager | dimension name | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | ? |
| a | 2 | ? |
| a | 3 | ? |
| b | 1 | ? |
| b | 2 | ? |
| b | 3 | ? |
| c | 1 | ? |
| c | 2 | ? |
| c | 3 | ? |

I can sum the `dimension value` to get the total value for that dimension for that `l1 manager`.

But what do I divide it by? I can't divide by summing `target score` or `current score` cause that'll essentially be multiplying the `target score` or `current score`.

I'm stuck/lost.